# extract part of html using tidy in php

Tags: php, html, parsing, tidy

I want to extract particular part of HTML using tidy in php.

the html page has table in it and i just want to fetch that table from html page.

please help and post the solution....

Thanks

Comment: This is more of an 'ask for help' than a 'do it for me' site

Comment: sorry the way i asked the question is wrong but my intention is to ask for a help only rather than posting the whole solution

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590496/need-help-with-php-dom-xpath-parsing-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PHP Simple DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is better suited for the job I think. There are good usage examples on the site.

A function to grab a table should look like this (untested but should work):

```
echo $html->find('table[id=mytable]', 0)->plaintext;
```